# onclick doesn't store variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to store the value of a input field into a variable. But it doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? I know there are other ways and I will probably change it later anyway. But right now I'm just really curious why this doesn't work:

http://codepen.io/ttimon/pen/PGYapa

```
<div id="searchInput" class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Type your search term here...">
  </div>
  <button id="search" class="button" onclick="searchWiki();">Search</button>

</div>



$( document ).ready(function() {
    function searchWiki() {
      var search = document.getElementbyId("usr").value;
      alert(search);
} 

});
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Move function `searchWiki` outside the scope of `document-ready` handler

Comment: Beside wrong placement of the function (it has to be outside of your "document-ready"), you also misspelled the javascript function: correct name would be "document.getElementById" (..By...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `searchWiki` to be invokable from `onclick` it needs to be in global scope.

Declare `searchWiki` outside `document.ready`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

});
function searchWiki() 
{
  var search = document.getElementById("usr").value;
  alert(search);
}
```

Comment: @gurvinger372 thanks, but it still doesn't work. error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

Comment: @user2317500 make it `getElementById`

Comment: @gurvinger372 ohh, yeah that was it. Ok thank you very much. Now I'll probably do what jfriend00 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You must be getting an error because the `searchWiki` function is not in scope. Move it out of the `document.ready` function...

```
function searchWiki() {
      var search = document.getElementbyId("usr").value;
      alert(search);
} 

$( document ).ready(function() {


});
```

Comment: thanks but as I commented below, it still gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

First off, stop using Javascript inside your HTML.  It is generally considered a good practice to follow [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) where you separate the Javascript and HTML and don't insert Javascript into your HTML, but rather use Javascript run at initialization time to "hook up" to your HTML.

Your existing code is getting an error because function names inserted inside the HTML must exist in the global scope, but your `searchWiki()` function is not in the global scope - it's inside the `.ready()` handler function so the symbol `searchWiki` doesn't exist in the global scope.

Then, since you already have jQuery, you can just hook up the click handler with jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div id="searchInput" class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="Type your search term here...">
  </div>
  <button id="search" class="button">Search</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search").click(function() {
        var search = $("#usr").val();
        alert(search);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<script src="prepare.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="searchInput" class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" placeholder="...">
    </div>
    <button id="search" class="button">Search</button>

    <script src="pageready.js"></script>
</body>
```